# How to Overlay or Superimpose an Image onto a Video in C#

Tags: c#, image, video, overlay, watermark

I'm trying to figure out how to overlay an image over a (saved file) video in Visual C#, and then resave it. I've been ripping my hair out trying to do this for the past four hours, looking everywhere, so any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Some additional details would be appreciated.  You need to explain what you have you tried and where you are stuck to get good feedback.

Comment: I don't know what I haven't tried. I've tried ffmpeg (which gave me some issue regarding not being able to find a file), I've tried splicer, but it kept bringing up different errors and didn't seem to have an option for it, and I've dabbled with directshow.net, but can't find any (literally any) documentation or examples to get started implementing it as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DirectShow.NET is a wrapper over DirectShow, a [previous generation] MS Multimedia API. The API itself is better suitable for native development, however .NET wrapper is pretty popular and powerful.

[DirectShow.NET samples](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/DirectShowSamples/2010-February/) include:

> Samples\Capture\DxLogo
> ---------------------- A sample application showing how to superimpose a logo on a data stream. It uses a  capture device for the video
> source, and outputs the result to a file.
>
> Samples\Players\DxText
> ---------------------- A sample application showing how to superimpose text strings on a datastream.   The stream is read from an avi file.

Comment: Finally... I'd heard of them but I'd never found them in the main package -- never realized they were in another package... Thank you so much -- saved me hours of time.