# Video with moving image as overlay using Flash or .NET

Tags: .net, html, actionscript-3, flash, video

I have a swf/mp4 video file. Within some frames I want to insert an uploaded image at a specific position of that frame. Then this video can be download that includes the image embedded.

Is this possible using `.net` framework, Flash, HTML5? For example, I have a video of a talking cartoon character. This character's face will be replaced by the user's uploaded face image.

Reference example : http://www.jibjab.com/ecards/thanks/super_hero_thanks

Comment: For the .Net portion of the solution, look at [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076775/how-to-overlay-or-superimpose-an-image-onto-a-video-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 3):

In Flash, you could take the approach of running a screen capture lib [similar to how this user has done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29748428/5488621). You'd play the video and put the image on top of the video object and move it at your leisure while recording. Save and you're done.

Note: based on your super hero example you would probably need to make a custom mask for each video you want to feature a face on.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in flash by uploading the image (via whatever method, .net, php etc) then when you generate the html for the flash video, you pass in the parameters of the image url in the params tags. If you need to do this at runtime, then you can use javascript to pass in the image url via [this page](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-communicate-between-flash-and-javascript--active-3370) can tell you how that's done.

Really though I would avoid flash. Its been a dying tech since Apple refused to let it run on iOS, and adobe have just announced that support for flash will end in 2020.

If you just want to create a video you can use a video editor and import the image to the screen there.